# HTML parsing with Beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is what my HTML looks like :

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  class="list04" style="width:704px;">

    <td class="txt"><img src="img/1001.gif" /></td>
    <td>
    <div>string1</div>
    <div>
    string2</div>
    </td>
    <td><div class="name">string3</div>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>


    <td class="txt"><img src="img/1002.gif" /></td>
    <td>
    <div>string4</div>
    <div>
    string5</div>
    </td>
    <td><div class="name">string6</div>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>

</table>
```

I want to extract strings (`string1` to `string6`) with Beautiful soup.

Can anyone answer me how to do this?

** there are so many `<div>`s in the rest of HTML and i don't need them all.
 I want to extract strings between `<td class="txt">` and `</td>`

Comment: To do that, we'd need to know what tags encapsulate those sections- give us some more HTML.

Comment: `<td class="txt">` and the next `</td>` are in the same line and thy don't contain any of the `<div>`s you're looking for. You might want to look at some the `<tr>` or `<table>` that contains them instead.

Comment: table looks like that.. sorry for confusion. i want to extract all the strings in table. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is in the string `html`, use

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print [t.text for t in soup.find("table", {"class": "list04"}).findAll("div")]
```

which will print out:

```
[u'string1', u'string2', u'string3', u'string4', u'string5', u'string6']
```

Comment: there are so many <div>s that i don't need. I want to extract strings between <td class="txt"> and </td>

Comment: You'll need to show us more HTML than that, then. As you have it set up, the only stuff in between <td class="txt"> and the corresponding </td> is the IMG tags. What are the rest of the tags?

Comment: I'd replace `t.contents[0].strip()` with just `t.text`.

Comment: there are no tags for other. </td> that i said was the one at last.

Comment: I edited my code so that it extracts the divs only from that specific table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 
f = open('a.htm')
soup = BeautifulSoup(f) 
anothersoup = BeautifulSoup(soup.findAll('td', attrs={'class':'txt'}))
list = anothersoup.findAll('div')
print list
```